# Is this the right way of advertising your personal blog?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering if its allowed to advertise your blog like,

> Regards, Michael (http://sp2013-blog.com)

User is posting it on most of his posts.

For example, [How to fix “A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/how-to-fix-a-sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on-this-computer-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Signatures are just noise. The profile page is where you should put all this stuff. There is a link to it from every post you make on the site.

Here's the [FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures):

> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be
>   removed.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
>   which links directly back to your user page.

For one-offs they can be edited out. If anyone is persistently doing this they can be contacted by a moderator if necessary.

---

Regards, best wishes and felicitations,

SPDoctor

My sig quote: A journey of a thousand miles starts with a single step, but there is still approximately a thousand miles to go.

My awesome blog site URL is at [SPDoctor.net](http://spdoctor.net/); please click on it because I check the traffic stats every day.

Sent from my computer.

Oops, did I go too far?

Answer (score 1):

Allowed is a funny word.  Signatures in general are frowned upon and generally get edited out.  This one seems particularly spammy.

The rule to follow is: only include information in your answer that is relevant.  If that is a link to your personal blog, go for it.

Generic links to your blog should go in your personal profile.

Check out the FAQ question from SO Meta for more information.

[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: I agree, but if a user is posting it in every single post, I think they should be informed then editing ten's of there posts, I guess.